# Rebasing a branch with sub-branches all at once

Tags: git, rebase

I often have sub-branches on a branch that I want to rebase onto the mainline. Consider this:

```
* (Mainline)
*
*
| * (topicA_Branch3)
| *
| *
| * (topicA_Branch2)
| *
| *
| * (topicA_Branch1)
| *
| *
|/
*
*
```

I want to move all three of these `topicA` branches onto mainline. Currently, I know two ways to do this:

1. While on `topicA_Branch3`, execute the command, `git rebase Mainline`.

   a. At this point, I would have to delete `topicA_Branch1` and `2` and manually re-create the branches on the correct commits on the now rebased `topicA_Branch3`.
2. Another way would be to do three separate commands:

   a. While on `topicA_Branch1`, do `git rebase Mainline`.

   b. `git rebase --onto topicABranch1 <topicA_Branch1-old-SHA> topicABranch2`

   c. `git rebase --onto topicABranch2 <topicA_Branch2-old-SHA> topicABranch3`

   d. This is kind of cumbersome...

**Is there a command that I want that will rebase a branch and bring it's sub-branches with it?**

To be clear, I want to end up with this:

```
* (topicA_Branch3)
*
*
* (topicA_Branch2)
*
*
* (topicA_Branch1)
*
*
* (Mainline)
*
*
*
*
```

Comment: As an interesting side note, `git filter-branch` contains all the machinery that would be required to do this automatically.  But `filter-branch` does not have any built in `rebase` functionality.  Plus it's a very big (sledge)hammer, vs this relatively simple problem. :-)

Comment: Is --onto always necessary? I feel like I was able to get the desired effect in a toy repo by simply doing

git checkout b1 && git rebase MainLine && git checkout b2 && git rebase b1 && git checkout b3 && git rebase b2
.
I guess this doesn't always work. When wouldn't the steps that I took not work? Just when there are conflicts? Seems that git sees that some commits are redundant, and doesn't freak out. Obviously, it's better if git does not try to replicate redundant commits, but it seems to deal with that ok. Maybe this is because newer versions of git are smarter, 8.7 years later.

Comment: Ofc, it would be better if there were a shorter command, but I feel that it's bearable if you don't need git rebase --onto X Y Z. Y is the most difficult to figure out, but even that is not too horrible, if you know about the Y@{1} trick, mentioned in one of the answers. And I believe Z is optional if you already have it checked out.

Answer (score 1):

What about that:

```
 a. While on `topicA_Branch1`, do `git rebase Mainline`.

 b. `git rebase --onto topicABranch1 topicABranch1@{1} topicABranch2`

 c. `git rebase --onto topicABranch2 topicABranch2@{1} topicABranch3` 

 d. ...
```

This might easily be automated. The syntax topicABranch1@{1} means ["the last known state of topicABranch1 before the rebase"](https://coderwall.com/p/xzsr9g/rebasing-dependent-branches-with-git)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is cumbersome, I am not aware of any existing do it all command. But it is scriptable. The commands to get from the first to second illustration are

```
for i in topicA_Branch1 topicA_Branch2 topicA_Branch3
do
    git branch $i._OrIg_ $i
done
# First branch directly
git rebase --onto Mainline topicA_Branch1
# Remaining branches
git rebase --onto topicA_Branch1 topicA_Branch1._OrIg_ topicA_Branch2
git rebase --onto topicA_Branch2 topicA_Branch2._OrIg_ topicA_Branch3
```

After you have verified things are correct you can delete the `*._OrIg_` branches. With this you only have to keep the script up to date with the names and sequence of the branches.

Update: You can create a list of all the branches, in sequence, with

```
 git rev-list --reverse --simplify-by-decoration Mainline..topicA_BranchN \
 | git name-rev --stdin --name-only
```

Here you are only dependent on knowing the name of the last `topicA_BranchN` branch, e.g. topicA_Branch3 in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git filter-branch` with an appropriate `--parent-filter`. Something like this:

```
git filter-branch --parent-filter 'sed -e "s/X/Y/"' --tag-name-filter cat -- branchA branchB branchC
```

Here `X` should be the hash of the first commit that is not on mainline but is on the other branches, and `Y` could just be `HEAD` or `Mainline` or the hash of the current head of `Mainline`...